# angular custom attribute directive should be replaced by another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I an trying to implement a custom attribute directive for a src-like attribute, that should represent a relative path to a directory.

The path to the directory is in a global variable (say mydir).

The attribute should be replaced with an ng-src combined with the directory path.

I want to use it like this:

```
<md-icon my-src="cake.svg"></md-icon>
<md-icon my-src="{{ anExpression }}"></md-icon>
<md-icon my-src="{{::onTimeBinding}}"></md-icon>
```

I also want to support this not just for angulat material use.

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

I am sorry I didn't explain my self well. I want to support the use of the mySrc directive in all kinds of elements. It should be replaced as ng-src with the base directory. I created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O1AIrWunpk8nzFsMSNPm) but it doesn't work.
The code looks like this so far:

```
app.directive("mySrc", function() {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    compile: function(element, attrs) {

      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attributes) {
          var baseUrl = 'http://dummyimage.com/';
          attributes.$set("ng-src", baseUrl + attributes.mySrc);
        }
      }

    }
  }
});
```

Example of use:

```
<img my-src="100" />
<img my-src="{{ expr }}" />
<img my-src="{{:: oneTimeExpr }}" />
```

It is important for us to support the last two options also.

Comment: can you paste your code of that directive that you have so far?

Comment: and your snippt is ?

Comment: Added a plunkr and the code i tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directive actually works, but your approach is slightly off.  You don't want to change `my-src` to `ng-src`, since `ng-src` is a directive that does something similar to what you are trying to do.  What you *actually* want to do is change `my-src` to `src`, so the browser can actually render the tag.

In other words, `attributes.$set("src", baseUrl + attributes.mySrc);` does what you want.  However, it's not dynamic.

Taken from the [source](http://plnkr.co/edit/vogwUGai8iMavk5elDVB?p=preview) for `ng-src`, you can use `$observe` to monitor your attribute for changes.

```
pre: function(scope, element, attributes) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://dummyimage.com/';
    attributes.$observe("mySrc", function(value) {
        attributes.$set("src", baseUrl + attributes.mySrc);
    })
}

<button ng-click="expr = '200'">Test dynamic</button>
```

I just added a quick button to test the dynamic change. With `$observe`, any time the `mySrc` attribute changes, the `src` attribute will be updated with the new URL.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vogwUGai8iMavk5elDVB?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can perform your required action in the directive implementation:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('mySrc', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<li><img ng-src="{{ image }}" /></li>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var baseUrl = 'http://dummyimage.com/';
          console.log(attrs);

          scope.image = baseUrl + attrs.mySrc;
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the working **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ciTcRl9PWp5cejPwubl?p=preview)**